# Missing datetime values in a time series, filling with carrying over the last value

Tags: datetime, lubridate, posixct

I have intraday time series, like this:

```
        01/12/2022 08:00    4545
    01/12/2022 08:01    85758
    01/12/2022 08:03    87786
    01/12/2022 08:04    456867
    01/12/2022 08:06    4278528
    01/12/2022 08:07    5682
    01/12/2022 08:08    428
    01/12/2022 08:09    5272
```

As you can see, my time series doesn't follow the right order, as for some minutes the table has missing rows. What I would like to do is to fill in the missing dates with time, and fill the missing value with the last value before it. I tried many things, but so far I couldn't manage to properly solve it. Any help would be welcome!

I already tried converting the datetime column into POSIXct format, but no luck with that. I was thinking of creating a vector of datetime, with seq, but I was not able to define minimum and maximum values, to be in the right order. The `max(datetime)` and `min(datetime)` only returned `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

### Data

```
data <-
  structure(list(date = c("01/12/2022 08:00", "01/12/2022 08:01", 
                          "01/12/2022 08:03", "01/12/2022 08:04", "01/12/2022 08:06", "01/12/2022 08:07", 
                          "01/12/2022 08:08", "01/12/2022 08:09"),
                 value = c(4545L, 85758L,87786L, 456867L, 4278528L, 5682L, 428L, 5272L)),
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-8L))
```

### Code

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <-
  data %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy_hm(date)) 

data.frame(date = seq.POSIXt(from = min(data$date), to = max(data$date),by = "min")) %>% 
  left_join(data) %>% 
  fill(value,.direction = "down")
```

### Output

```
Joining, by = "date"
                  date   value
1  2022-12-01 08:00:00    4545
2  2022-12-01 08:01:00   85758
3  2022-12-01 08:02:00   85758
4  2022-12-01 08:03:00   87786
5  2022-12-01 08:04:00  456867
6  2022-12-01 08:05:00  456867
7  2022-12-01 08:06:00 4278528
8  2022-12-01 08:07:00    5682
9  2022-12-01 08:08:00     428
10 2022-12-01 08:09:00    5272
```

Comment: The problem is that when I am defining `to = max(Data$Date)` and `from=min(Data$Date)` it returns me a `NA` ... And I don't have a clue how to solve that...

Comment: Did you run my code with `lubridate`?

Comment: Actually yes, I got it to work with `to = last(Data$Date)` and `from = first(Data$Date)`